# Best practice to update dependency v-calendar from beta to v2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dependencies, updates, vcalendar

what is the best practice to upgrade the dependency v-calendar from `beta` to the latest version v2.3.0?

I know the question is opinion based, but I am new to the field, what are the pros and cons of the way to do the upgrade.

We use `"v-calendar": "~1.0.0-beta.14"` in production. The latest version is currently [v.2.3.0](https://vcalendar.io/changelog/v2.0.html#v2-3-0)

I can think of two ways:

1. update to the latest version with `yarn add v-calendar@latest`?
2. upgrade incrementally until the latest version is reached with `yarn upgrade "v-calendar"`?

What should I do to reach the latest version? thank you

ps. we are using `vue: ~2.6.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the package you are using has an upgrade guide (99.99% of them don't), **there is absolutely no point** in doing an incremental upgrade. If it has an upgrade guide, read and follow its instructions.

The easiest way to upgrade is to change the package version to latest (in most IDE's if you press Ctrl/Cmd and hover the package number shown in `package.json` a tooltip will show you currently installed version, latest wanted version and latest available version). After you changed it (by typing the latest version in), run `yarn install`.

In the vast majority of cases, that's all you need to do, because most packages are built with backwards compatibility (existing features remain and new features are being added). If that's not true in your case, you'll have to reimplement it following their documentation. Typically it's no big deal.

Also, note there is no risk in attempting to change to a newer version. If things break, you just go back to `package.json`, change version back to lower, run `yarn install` again and everything is back to square one.

Comment: Thanks, the version display in the package.json was new to me. Will try it out.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I will take your answer into consideration when I upgrade other packages as well. I will now see if there were any inconsistencies in the upgrade. Thanks again.

Comment: @witt, run [`yarn outdated`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/outdated/) to see a list of everything that's outdated. This command also considers dependencies (some packages require other packages to be in a particular range - that's also taken into account when you get the `wanted` version, which might be lower than the `latest` version).